# Loading PNG with stb_image for OpenGL texture gives wrong colors

Tags: c++, opengl, png, textures, alpha

I am using stb_image to load a 32-bit PNG file (RGBA) and I am creating an OpenGL texture with it.

It works fine for 24-bit PNG files (with no alpha channel), but when I use a 32-bit PNG file, something goes wrong.

This is what the texture should look like:

[image: Texture]

And this is what it looks like when rendered with OpenGL (the black parts are meant to be transparent, and are when I enable blending):

[image: Wrong Texture]

This is how I load the texture:

```
int w;
int h;
int comp;
unsigned char* image = stbi_load(filename.c_str(), &w, &h, &comp, STBI_rgb);

if(image == nullptr)
    throw(std::string("Failed to load texture"));

glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

if(comp == 3)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
else if(comp == 4)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

stbi_image_free(image);
```

And these are the window parameters (using SDL)

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
```

What is happening?

Comment: ++ convert tensor

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Changing the STBI_rgb to STBI_rgb_alpha in the stbi_load function call fixed it.

Probably best not to specify RGB when its RGBA :D

Answer (score 50):

Your actual bug is that you use `comp` to determine your `format` (`GL_RBA`/`GL_RGBA`) parameter to `glTexImage2D`. This happens because when you load an image using `stbi_load`, the value returned in `comp` will always match the source image, not the image data returned.

More specifically, your bug is that you use `STBI_rgb`, causing `stbi_load` to return 3 byte pixels, but then you load it with `glTexImage2D` as 4 byte pixels with `GL_RGBA` because `comp` is 4 when you load a 32 bit image.

You must set the format in your call to `glTexImage2D` to `GL_RGB` if you use `STBI_rgb` and to `GL_RGBA` if you use `STBI_rgb_alpha`.

**Bonus to other readers**

Are you having a similar problem and the above still doesn't help? Then your image data might not have rows on the alignment OpenGL expects. Try `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before you call `glTexImage2D`. See https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_layout for more information.

Comment: I've encountered the need for GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT with stb_image a few times.  stb_image documentation indicates that it does not try to perform any kind of alignment - and most certainly that becomes clear when handing OpengGL an NPOT (non-power-of-two) texture without said alignment.  POT textures will be naturally aligned, while NPOT textures will not be.